# $\left\{\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{2K\pi}{3}\Big\vert K\in\mathbb {Z}\right\}\cap\left\{\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{K\pi}{2}\Big\vert K\in\mathbb {Z}\right\}=$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$\left\{\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{2K\pi}{3}\,\Big\vert\, K\in\mathbb {Z}\right\}\cap\left\{\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{K\pi}{2}\,\Big\vert\vert\, K\in\mathbb {Z}\right\}=\varnothing$$

Is my answer right? If not, why?

Comment: How did you get to your answer?  (Hint: it may be easier to manipulate if you consider the terms of each set to be of the form $\frac{\pi}6\times x$ and look at what your $x$ values can be.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I'm just interested if I got the answer right.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki pi/6+2Kpi/3 & pi/6+pi(3K+1/6) so they are different

Comment: If you want to know why your answer might be wrong, it helps the people answering to understand why you think your answer is correct.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki We want to compare $\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{2K\pi}{3}$ with $\pi/3+\frac{K\pi}2$ so we do : $$\pi/3+\frac{K\pi}2=\pi/6+\pi/6+\frac{K\pi}2=\pi/6+\pi(\frac16+\frac{3K}{6}=\pi/6+\frac{\pi(3K+1)}{6}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A broad hint: the two sets can be written as $\{\frac\pi6\cdot (1+4K)\}$ and $\{\frac\pi6\cdot(2+3J)\}$.  (Since $K$ can be arbitrary, it helps to use different variables for the two sets so you don't inadvertently try to solve an equation in $K$).  In other words, the intersection of the two sets will have the form $\{\frac\pi6\cdot N\}$ whenever we can write $N=1+4K$ and also write $N=2+3J$ (in other words, $N$ is one more than a multiple of $4$, and two more than a multiple of $3$).

Now, what numbers $N$ are of the form $N=1+4K$ and also of the form $N=2+3J$?  (Here's a broad hint: consider numbers of the form $N=X+12Y$ (the 12 here comes in as the LCM of 3 and 4).  Now, if $X+12Y = 1+4K$ and $X\lt 12$, then $X$ must be either 1, or 5, or 9: $1+12Y = 1+4K$ where $K=3Y$, $5+12Y = 1+4K$ where $K=3Y+1$, and $9+12Y = 1+4K$ where $K=3Y+2$.  But we also have that $X+12Y = 2+3J$; can you figure out what values of $X$ make this possible?  (Notice that for $X+12Y = 1+4K$ we started with $X=1$ and then got $5=1+4$ and $9=5+4$).

Comment: the numbers of the form $K=\frac{1+3J}{4}$ where $1+3J$ is a multiple of $4$,no?

Comment: Try writing out what those numbers look like, and see if you recognize any patterns.

Comment: I found out that $1$ is the only odd solution, let me try with even solutions. **EDIT:** The other solution is $1/2$.

Comment: So , please I'm more confused now!!

Comment: I amended my solution to try and explain in somewhat more detail.  Try and keep in mind that you're not looking for $K$ itself here...

Comment: So basically at the end Iwill get that the answer is $\emptyset$

Comment: @user143592 What numbers do you get for values $2+3J$?